# how replace <tag value="value"> to $tag['$thepreviousvalue'] with regexp

Tags: php

Hello there i've finally made a good *perfect* language system and now am trying to fix my templates system to work with this new language system =P
i want to replace  to $tag['$thepreviousvalue'] so i made the following code

```
preg_replace("/<LANGUAGE value=\"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}$\">/si", ''. $langvals['$1'] .'', $data);
```

but it doesn't work and i bet that my weak knowledge in regexp is the problem.

Comment: You can achieve this easily and more secure with a DOM parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/your_regex/e', '$var[\'$1\']', $string);
```

In your case:

```
preg_replace('/<LANGUAGE value="([a-z0-9_]+?)">/ei', '$langvals[\'$1\']', $data);
```

You can read more about the "e" modifier at [php.net](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Also, I fixed your regex.

Comment: *(suggested reading)* [Regular Expression Injection (PDF)](http://hauser-wenz.de/playground/papers/RegExInjection.pdf)

Comment: oh Gordon, thanks for the book...it has Great info to know BUT,i think there is no risk here...am replacing language tag with its value thats all, and there is no Post Or Get here, just a regular use in templates...maybe you have another idea

Comment: @SAFAD that depends on the viewpoint. From a pragmatic POV this is nothing to bother if you are the only one authoring the tags, but from a less situational POV the code is dangerous.